# Proving continuity and boundedness of the Fourier Transform

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, fourier-transform

> Let $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb R^d)$. Define the Fourier transform of $f$ by $$\hat{f}(y)=\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\cdot y}\,dx\,\,\,\,(y\in\mathbb R^d).$$
>   Show that $\hat{f}:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function and $\|\hat{f}\|_{\infty}\leq\|f\|_{1}.$

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$ First we prove continuity. Let $y\in\mathbb R^d$ be arbitrary but fixed, and let $(y_n)_n\subset\mathbb R^d$ such that $y_n\to y$ as $n\to\infty$. Then for every $x\in\mathbb R^d$ we have that $f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\cdot y_n}\to f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\cdot y}$ as $n\to\infty$, since the function $y\mapsto e^{-2\pi ix\cdot y}$ is continuous. Now observe that $\vert f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\cdot y_n}\vert\leq\vert f(x)\vert$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^d.$ Therefore by the Dominated convergence theorem, it follows that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\hat{f}(y_n)=\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\cdot y}\,dx=\hat{f}(y).$$ Since $y\in\mathbb R^d$ was arbitrary, the function $\hat{f}:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb{C}$ is continuous.

Now we prove that $\|\hat{f}\|_{\infty}\leq\|f\|_{1}.$ Note that for all $y\in\mathbb R^d$ we have $$\vert \hat{f}(y)\vert\leq\int_{\mathbb R^d}\vert f(x)\vert\vert e^{-2\pi ix\cdot y}\vert\,dx=\|f\|_{1}.$$ Since the above holds for all $y\in\mathbb R^d$, it follows that $\|\hat f(y)\|_{\infty}\leq\|f\|_{1}.$

---

Do you agree with the my proof?

Any feedback is much welcomed. Thank your for your time.

Comment: Sounds right to me...

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct, but I think it is not the best possible: you use the Dominated convergence theorem, which is quite a strong result, only to prove continuity of the Fourier transform.

Another proof could be based on

$|\hat{f}(y+h)-\hat{f}(y)|=|\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)e^{-2\pi i x\cdot y}(e^{-2\pi ix\cdot h-1})|
\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f(x)||e^{-2\pi i x\cdot h}-1|$

This equation one has the advantage not do depend on $y$, and from this we deduce that the continuity is uniform (some work is required to show it thought, since $|e^{-2\pi i x\cdot h}-1|$ doesn't go to $0$ uniformly), and we did this without appelling to $\hat{f}$ the Dominated  convergence theorem.

For what concerns the boundedness of $\hat{f}$, your proof is perfectly fine.

Comment: In my opinion anyone studying Fourier transforms of $L^{1}$ function should have no hesitation to use DCT, MCT etc.  However if we are specifically asked to prove uniform continuity, then your comment on OP's proof is very reasonable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes, you are right

Comment: Why do you think you've shown the continuity is uniform? $ |e^{-2\pi i x\cdot h}-1|$ is not uniformly small.

Comment: @zhw. Because the bound on the distance does not depend on $y$ but only on $h$. Thus, for $\epsilon>0$ small enough, we can obtain a relation such that $|x-x_0|<h \rightarrow |\hat{f}(x)-\hat{f}(x_0)|<\epsilon$

Comment: @zhw. The integral will have to be divided in pieces to avoid too much oscillations caused by the dipendence on $x$ ( or maybe using an approximation of $f$ with compact-supported functions), but doing this will result in proving the uniform continuity

Comment: Yes but your answer makes it sound like this is trivial. We don't have $e^{-2\pi i x\cdot h}-1\to 0$ uniformly, so more work is needed to get the uniform continuity of $\hat f.$

Comment: @zhw. You are right, I edited the answer to make it explicit

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The DCT is saying that if $\forall n, |f_n(t)| \le h(t)$ with $h \in L^1$ (or $L^1_{loc}$) and $f_n$ converges pointwise then $f_n$ converges in $L^1$ (or $L^1_{loc}$). Don't you think it is obfuscating to use it when unnecessary (which is quite always the case) ?

Comment: @reuns The DCT works fine in proving continuity. The dominating function, globally, is simply $|f|.$